# Add remove class for slide in div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a header that has 2 positions 1 absolute and fixed when you scroll I need the header to smoothly slide in and when you scroll back to the top it will slide out.. I cannot get it to slide it just shows up and out when scrolling.

```js
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {    
       $('.header').addClass('fixed');
            } else { 
    $('.header').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.header { 
  position: absolute; 
  width:100%; 
  height:86px;  
  background:  red;
  color: #fff;
}
.header.fixed { 
  width:100%; 
  height:66px; 
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  background:#000;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-130px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-130px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-130px);
   transform: translateY(-130px);
   transition: transform .5s ease;
}
.header.fixed {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="header">
  <span>My Div</span>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 2000px; background-color: grey;">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I go to the solution, it's better to use `left: 0, right: 0` to make absolute elements `100% width` than `width: 100%`.

change your styles on `.fixed` to:

```
.header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  // absolute 100% width
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height:66px;
  background:#000;
  color: #fff;
  // the slide animation when fixed class appears
  animation: headerSlideIn 0.5s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
} 

// the slide in animation
@keyframes headerSlideIn {
  0% {
    // make it start -66px which is away from your screen
    top:-66px;
  }

  100% {
    // the key to your animation
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Thus it will give you the desired result. If you do not like `top` implementation because of it's jerky behavior on mobile simply replace it with `transform: translateY()` and make it `top: 0`.

Also the reason the old code is not working is:

```
// you overwritten your style above with 0 which simply doesn't do anything
.header.fixed {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

hope that helps.

```js
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300)
            {
              $('.header').removeClass('slide-back');
           $('.header').addClass('fixed');
           }
            else if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0)
            {
          $('.header').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.header { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height:86px;
  background:  red;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  height: 66px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  animation: headerSlideIn 0.5s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes headerSlideIn {
  0% {
    top:-66px;
  }
  
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="header">
  <span>My Div</span>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 2000px; background-color: grey;">Content</div>
```

Comment: if you scroll back up it don't slide out it just disappears

Comment: There is no good way to slide that back because user is moving the scrollbar, you will see a really bad sluggish animation. You need to improvise on how you are going to pull that out, one of those will be removing `fixed` class when it reached the end `scrollTop == 0` and not `scrollTop < 300` or just simply make it position fixed by default. Updated answer for `scrollTop == 0` solution.